# UWP MediaPlayer : Play encrypted HLS stream by passing the key from app

Tags: encryption, uwp, video-streaming, media-player, http-live-streaming

I am looking for a way to play the encrypted HLS streams in UWP MediaElement , I am able to play the url that has key url given but I need to pass the key from app, not from the key url.

#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="stream.m3u8.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000

IF the key file is present the below code works fine.

```
 async private void InitializeAdaptiveMediaSource(System.Uri uri)
    {
        AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationResult result = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync(uri);

        if (result.Status == AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationStatus.Success)
        {
            ams = result.MediaSource;
            mediaPlayerElement.SetMediaPlayer(new Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer());
            mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromAdaptiveMediaSource(ams);

            mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.AutoPlay = true;
            mediaPlayerElement.Stretch = Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.Stretch.Uniform;

            ams.InitialBitrate = ams.AvailableBitrates.Max<uint>();

            //Register for download requests
            ams.DownloadRequested += DownloadRequested;

            ////Register for download failure and completion events
            //ams.DownloadCompleted += DownloadCompleted;
            //ams.DownloadFailed += DownloadFailed;

            ////Register for bitrate change events
            //ams.DownloadBitrateChanged += DownloadBitrateChanged;
            //ams.PlaybackBitrateChanged += PlaybackBitrateChanged;

            ////Register for diagnostic event
            //ams.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAvailable += DiagnosticAvailable;
        }
        else
        {
            //// Handle failure to create the adaptive media source
            //MyLogMessageFunction($"Adaptive source creation failed: {uri} - {result.ExtendedError}");
        }
    }
```

But I want to pass the key from my app to decrypt the video and play in the MediaElement.Any help regarding this is greatly appriciated.

Comment: Have you tried to [Initialize an AdaptiveMediaSource using HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming#initialize-an-adaptivemediasource-using-httpclient) to pass the key.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your comment , I also tried with : Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAppendWithoutValidation("KEY", "MY_KEY_VALUE");
            AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationResult result = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromUriAsync(uri, httpClient);                                                   But In my case Key file is not present to the url, I need to pass the value of key from my app,If key file present It works fine.So looking for help from the community

Comment: We suggest you use the fiddler to catch the response and detect where you could place  the key value.